# why is my sms reciever code not responding

Tags: java, android

I'm a newbie to android programming
I am trying to read incoming SMS and the SMS sender number and display it in my app.

As soon as my phone receives an SMS the app closes

Is there a simple Solution, Should I not be using two classes in the same activity

```
package com.example.readnewmsg;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.databinding.DataBindingUtil;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Telephony;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;

import com.example.readnewmsg.databinding.ActivityMainBinding;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ActivityMainBinding binding;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);
    }


    public class SmsListner extends BroadcastReceiver {


        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (intent.getAction().equals(Telephony.Sms.Intents.SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION)) {
                String smsSender = "";
                String smsBody = "";
                for (SmsMessage smsMessage : Telephony.Sms.Intents.getMessagesFromIntent(intent)) {
                    smsBody += smsMessage.getMessageBody();
                    smsSender += smsMessage.getOriginatingAddress();
                        binding.MsgText.setText(smsBody);
                        binding.NoView.setText(smsSender);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I have Added these permissions in My manifest file

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
```

And also these intent filters

```
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver android:name=".MainActivity$SmsListner">
            <intent-filter android:priority="999">
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
```

Comment: Your `SmsListner` class would need to be `static`, as well, to be able to register it in the manifest. You're likely getting an `InstantiationException` since it's not.

Comment: Actually it shouldn't be a subclass at all.  I suppose it could be if you used a static one, but at that point it may as well be a separate top level class.

Comment: And when asking about a crash, post the stack trace from logcat.